# Relaxing the Rotating Wave Approximation in the analysis of a 2-level maser using time-dependent perturbation theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Having recently studied TDPT for masers, I wanted to go back and relax the RWA to see what would happen. What I find is that, assuming all atoms are injected into the maser in an excited state, then the probability of transitioning to the ground state given a time-varying electric field in the maser cavity is:

$P \propto \dfrac{t^2}{2}\text{sinc}^2([\omega_0-\omega]t/2) + \dfrac{t^2}{2}\text{sinc}^2([\omega_0+\omega]t/2) + \dfrac{1}{\omega_0^2-\omega^2}(2\text{cos}^2(\omega t)-2\text{cos}(\omega_0t)\text{cos}(\omega t))$

While I understand that the first term is what we have when we make the RWA and that the second term is small for a resonant transition (which is why we can make the RWA near resonance in the first place), the final term is really confusing me as it drives the probability to be negative for certain frequencies. How do we interpret this final term physically? Having looked into negative probabilities in QM, I have used the double slit example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability) to reason that this final term is somehow related to the transition occurring both at resonance $(\omega=\omega_0)$ and at $\omega=2\omega_0$ simultaneously and hence is not physical? Any help interpreting this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have got a so called "secularity", the polynomial term in $t$, that can move to non-nonsensical probabilities. There are some ways to eliminate this problem. A possible one is given in https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0404692 but I think you can find other ways in literature and it is a matter of taste which one to use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.